# Normal distribution realizations

Tags: matlab, probability, normal-distribution

Hi I am trying to generate values using Matlab for the question below:

Let `x` be a random variable with distribution N(0,1). Determine in an exact or approximate way:

> E{x^2}
>
> ```
> X=[-5:5];
> Y=normpdf(X);
> x2=X.*X;
> ex2=sum(x2.*Y);
> ```

I get the answer 1 which I assume is correct. But when I increase the realizations of `X`, i.e.

```
X=[-5:0.5:5];
Y=normpdf(X);
x2=X.*X;
ex2=sum(x2.*Y);
```

I get the answer as 2. Am I going wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are numerically computing the second moment of a Gaussian random variable. That's expressed in terms of the pdf as an *integral*, which you *approximate by a sum*.

To approximate the integral by a sum, you need to *multiply by the sampling step* used on the *x* axis. (you can think that the "*dx*" in the integral is replaced by a non-infinitesimal "Δ*x*"). The step is `1` in the first case, and `0.5` in the second.

So you need to multiply your second result by the step `0.5`.